# Test account for In App purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I made a test account for testing IAP, and purchased successfully, but after that, every time I open the app it would pop up a window to let me sign in with that apple id.
How to avoid that?

Comment: Have you bought a Auto-Renewing Subscription?

Comment: Is this on the simulator or a real device?  What AppleID account is the device signed into (not which AppleID did you use to make the purchase, those can be two different things)?

Comment: @fbara On a real device, and the test account  is different  with the signed one, because I just want to test IAP so I did not use my major account.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.make sure that you call

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

for all three states of the transactions: SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased, SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored, SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed.

Situation: you had registered some testuserxyz@t.com and tested IAP with it and not finished some transaction. Then you registered testuserabc@t.com. So, if you open app (be wanting to test it with testuserabc@t.com), you will see dialog with input credentials for testuserxyz@t.com! Even if you delete testuserxyz@t.com user from ITC - this dialog will appeared again, until you input correct credentials for your old user (testuserxyz@t.com). After this dialog willn't appear! It is working for me

Comment: Hi Rajesh,I do have the code `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];`  and the problem  is still exist.

Comment: Please All Step Review And Implement  
  1)  On the device Log out of iTunes account in settings (also hard close settings and iTunes if you have them open as a precaution)
  2)  Delete app
   3) Create a new test user at “itunesconnect.apple.com” – selecting the United States as your store
   4) Reinstall app
   5) Try to make a purchase in the app
   6) Enter you new test user account details
   7) If a pop up states that it needs to swap stores, immediately press home. DO NOT press OK.
   8) Relaunch the app, and try again. It should now work as expected.